# How to check macro argument?

Tags: macros, m4

How to refer to the argument of a macro in the definition of some other macro?

For eg, FOO(abc) is a macro. Suppose I want to write some other macro 'BAR' which is checking the argument of FOO first and if it 'abc', expands to one line and if not, expands to some other line.

BAR(if FOO_arg is abc)
{do this}
else
{do this}

How can it be achieved using m4 macros?

Comment: [m4](http://mbreen.com/m4.html)

Comment: Is `bar` being invoked from within `foo`?  If not, what is the relationship between the two?